# Steal.js: jQuery not found after compilation

Tags: stealjs

I am facing a strange error which I can't get resolved after googling and poking around.

So in my main.js, I have
`import $ from 'jquery';`

Loading my dev.html all works fine, but after running nmp run build, and loading index.html, I get

```
steal.production.js:11 ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        at eval (jquery.dotdotdot:3)
        at Function.eval (app.js:3)
```

So I also added
`import jQuery from 'jquery';` -> no result
Loading jquery directly in my index.html removes the error but just leads to other issues down the road. So I think I should get this fixed to get my deployment done.

Many thanks for your support.

Nada

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, package.json pointed to a test.js file.